# Generating bundle with SensioGeneratorBundle gives error symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm getting trouble generating a new bundle siwth sensio/generator-bundle, symfony ^3.4, what i do is:

```
> symfony new calendar --version=^3.4
> cd calendar
>  composer require sensio/generator-bundle

> php bin/console generate:bundle:
> planning on sharing this bundle: yes
>  Bundle namespace: Nmateo/CalBundle
> Bundle name"NmateoCalBundle": [enter]
> Target Directory"src/": [enter]
> Configuration format"xml": [enter]

> symfony new calendar --version=^3.4
> cd calendar
> composer require sensio/generator-bundle

> php bin/console generate:bundle:
> planning on sharing this bundle: yes
> Bundle namespace: Nmateo/CalBundle
> Bundle name"NmateoCalBundle": [enter]
> Target Directory"src/": [enter]
> Configuration format"xml": [enter]
```

Then i get this message:

> The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
>     You'll need to make the following changes manually.
>     -Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
>     namespace in the "autoload" section:
>
> -Edit /home/nmateo/Documents/calendar/src/Kernel.php
>     and add the following bundle in the AppKernel::registerBundles() method:
>     new Nmateo\CalBundle\NmateoCalBundle(),

So i registered it in autoloader:

```
   "autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Nmateo\\CalBundle\\": "src/Nmateo/CalBundle/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/",
        "Nmateo\\CalBundle\\": "src/Nmateo/CalBundle/"
    }
},
```

and added new Nmateo CalBundle NmateoCalBundle to the end of registerBundles in Kernel.php:

```
    public function registerBundles()
{
    $contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
    foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
        if ($envs[$this->environment] ?? $envs['all'] ?? false) {
            yield new $class();
        }
    }
    new Nmateo\CalBundle\NmateoCalBundle();
}
```

and do the composer dump-autoload:

Generated autoload files containing 0 classes

And then i start my server and got this error, i tried many times..:
[image]

EDIT: Sorry for the text in codes quote but the stackoverflow is giving me headaches since it dont want to publish my question it says: please place your code in code quotes buy all my code was already in codes quotes..

Answer (score 2):

Read GitHub repository before use any bundle. This bundle can`t works well with Symfony 4.0

Symfony 3.4 is equal to LTS Symfony 4.0

Sensiolabs uses *.4th versions as feature-freeze version.

---

https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle

"WARNING: This bundle does not support Symfony 4. It also does not support the new bundle-less directory structure as created by Symfony Flex. Use the Maker bundle instead."

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 3.4 has an issue with generating a new bundle its a known issue,
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/1098 
to fix that change your code as below

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
    "": "src/"
}
```

What we did is that we specified in the composer that every new generated bundle will be imported from `/src`

To finish the procedure you'll need to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

make sure you have the file `composer.phar` or download it from here  https://getcomposer.org/download/

hope it helps

Comment: You may have changed something before I would recommend remaking a new project and then do these steps